# Route not correctly segmented

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I defined a link in my view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Baxter", "Label", new { LabelName = "Baxter" })
```

I defined a route to catch this link like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        "Search Affaire Only Label", // Route name
        "{controller}/Label/{LabelName}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Affaire", action = "SearchAffaires", LabelName = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

The link works but the url is not correctly segmented in the address bar as you can see below:

```
http://localhost:3817/Affaire/Label?LabelName=Baxter
```

I thought the url would be formatted like this:

```
http://localhost:3817/Affaire/Label/Baxter
```

What's wrong? Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your anchor you are passing `Label` as action name (the second argument of the `ActionLink` helper) whereas in your route definition you have defined the `SearchAffaires` action. So either fix your anchor by also including the controller:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Baxter", "SearchAffaires", new { LabelName = "Baxter" })
```

or more explicitly give the controller name as well to avoid any ambiguity:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Baxter", "SearchAffaires", "Affaire", new { LabelName = "Baxter" }, null)
```

or modify your route definition to use the `Label` action on the `Affaire` controller.